# How to know MS SQL Server Database version? 2005 or 2008, for example?

Tags: sql-server

I want to know the version of an "mdf" MS SQL Server database file.

I have the "SQL Server Management Studio" tool for help if it's needed.

in the "Properties" of the mdf file, I've found: "Version -> 10.xxx"

Regards.....

Comment: are you asking how to tell what version of the MDF file format you have without attaching it to the sql server? if the MDF is attached it will be in the current version as SQL server upgrades the MDF when it is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 10 is SQL Server 2008